# How to execute background thread after server startup?

Tags: python, django

I'd like to execute some python code after Django server startup. This code has an infinite loop and will run in the background until server shutdown. It accesses the database and various internet services. At the same time users should be able to use the front end webpages and have database access as well.

Comment: @Amber celery is a sophisticated asynchronous queue management system. All I need is start one background thread on startup

Comment: celery isn't the only answer listed on that question.

Comment: You need to start a thread or a subprocess. There are many options to do that, and plenty of questions here that ask that question, with answers.

Comment: @LennartRegebro The linked question doesn't explain how to execute the code at startup

Comment: @bizso09: If you find the answers unclear you can comment on them there for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to start a subprocess on startup, there are a few bits to clear up:

1. By 'startup', you *have* to mean when an individual Django thread is started.
2. If you've got Django under a multiple-thread-proxying setup, and you
   just want to have one subprocess, regardless of how many Django
   threads are running on your box, you'll need to sort out some way of
   either checking whether your subprocess has already been started, or
   turn your 'subprocess' into a full-formed process/service of its
   own, and use some type of daemon manager to start both Django and
   your subprocess.

That said, the easiest place to patch in would likely be `settings.py`. This file/module is imported once, when a Django thread starts up.

You could also do it within `wsgi.py`, if you're using a WSGI proxying setup.

For the 'how to start a thread' answer, [please see this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602761/django-background-task).