# Python - On form submit send email and save record in database taking huge time

Tags: python, django, forms, performance, amazon-s3

I am writing a form submit in my application written in python/Django.Form has an attachment(upto 3MB) uploaded. On submit it has to save the attachment in aws s3, save the other data in database and also send emails.
This form submit is taking too much time and the UI is hanging.
Is there any other way to do this in python/django?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602761/django-background-task it might help you by doing it in background jobs

Answer (score 0):

The usual solution to tasks that are too long to be handled synchronously and can be handled asynchronously is to delegate them to some async queue like celery.

In your case, saving the form's data to db should be quite fast so I would not bother with this part, but moving the uploaded file to s3 and sending mails are good candidates.

Comment: Thank you. But is there anything light weight which can handle this? I wanted to try using threads but because of GIL in CPython I heard we do not get any use out of using threads.

Comment: The GIL will prevent threads to take advantage of other available processors on a multiprocessor hardware. It doesn't mean there's no use for threads, but multiprocessing has much more benefits - like executing async processes on another server etc...

Comment: Thank you Bruno. I have tried using thread. Created two threads to do the tasks. These run in background and on frontend the UI is not hanging.

Comment: If there is an exception in the method which the thread is executing? How to handle it. Will python terminate the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You have to profile your piece of code to understand what is the most time consuming.

**If your upload to S3** is taking to much time, you can either have something asynchronous to avoid hanging your webpage or having a thread which will continue the upload in background and notify once completed.

**If your insert into the DB** is taking to much time, you can add a queue, eg. [SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/?nc1=h_ls) to write your data once the database is less loaded. Of course this can be done only if your application don't rely on read consistency after write.

**If your email sending** is too long, you should consider using [SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/?nc1=h_ls) to avoid any backend latency issue.